# grep from two variables

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to eliminate the duplicate lines of a list like this.

```
LINES='opa
opa
eita
eita
argh'

DUPLICATE='opa
eita'
```

The output I am looking for is `argh`. 
Till now, this is what I tried:

```
echo -e "$DUPLICATE" | grep --invert-match -Ff- <(echo -e "$LINES")
```

And:

```
grep --invert-match -Ff- <(echo -e "$DUPLICATE") <(echo -e "$LINES")
```

But unsuccessfuly.

I know that I can achieve this if I put the content of `$LINES` into a file:

```
echo -e "$DUPLICATE" | grep --invert-match -Ff- FILE
```

But I'd like to know if this is possible only with variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a dash as the file name to `-f` means "read from stdin". Get rid of it so the file name given to `-f` is the process substitution.

There's no need for `echo -e`, and `-v` is shorter and more common than `--invert-match`.

```
echo "$LINES" | grep -vFf <(echo "$DUPLICATE")
```

Equivalently, using a herestring:

```
grep -vFf <(echo "$DUPLICATE") <<< "$LINES"
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach which doesn't require to create a duplicate list separately,

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for(k in a) if(a[k]==1) print k}' <<< "$LINES"
```

count occurrence of each line, print only if it's not duplicated (count==1).